# Automatically insert into one column while inserting into another column by default

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose I have two columns in a table. If I had tried to insert into one column then automatically the value should be present in another column also.
But I don't want to use triggers due to performance.

I saw some where while adding a new column he used "expression" after datatype

Please help me.

Comment: Why do you want to have two identical columns at all? What sort of an RDBMS design is it?

Comment: Are you talking about default value?

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clearer? It suggests that you want to  put identical values into two columns, but from your previous comment I don't think that's what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called a computed column.

This example will create a column (called *InventoryValue*) that will contain a value based on two other columns (*QtyAvailable* and *UnitPrice*).

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products 
(
    ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
  , QtyAvailable smallint
  , UnitPrice money
  , InventoryValue AS QtyAvailable * UnitPrice
);
```

Note:

The value of *InventoryValue* will be computed at SELECT-time, not during insert/update. If you want it to be computed at INSERT-time then you need to mark it as PERSISTED. This is especially important if you are using *getdate* functions in your computation.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products 
(
    ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
  , QtyAvailable smallint
  , UnitPrice money
  , InventoryValue AS QtyAvailable * UnitPrice PERSISTED
);
```

Persisted computed columns can be used in indexes and foreign keys.

Comment: Suggest you add that `InventoryValue` is computed on select, not on insert/update.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl
(
    ID int 

  , col2 AS ID )
```